# receive the log stack on error with AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using a serverless architecture with AWS API gateway and lambda.
On error( 4XX or 5XX ) I can find the complete stack trace on X-ray/cloudwatch easily
I would like to receive the stack trace using a lambda or something like that.
do you have any idea on how i could do that with cloudwatch and x-ray ?or anything else?

i did try to get an alarm when there is an error and while working it does not provide any useful information, i am just getting an alarm that inform of a problem with the dimension selected